# aceptar politica de privacidad de una web

Tags: python, selenium

necesito hacer click en un link, concretamente en Aceptar, de un HTML,  pero el problema que tengo es que llamo (uso get de selenium) a la web y ese HTML donde estar aceptar no me lo encuentra (o no sé si lo hago mal), pero creo que es un "otro elemento aparte de la web". Es un "pop text" típico donde se informa de la política de cookies y demás término de uso de la web y necesito dar a aceptar para que me deje interactuar con la pagina...

A alguien se le ocurre como hacerlo?

Mi codigo:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 
driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\\Users\\Usuario\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe') 
driver.get('infocif.es') 
cif=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtempresabusquedaprincipal']") 
cif.send_keys('ELQUESEA') 
cif.submit()
```

Muchas gracias de antemano. Un saludo

Comment: Cada pagina tiene su propio mensaje, si nos pudieras indicar la pagina que intentas automatizar o alguna parecida, podriamos ayudarte mejor. Si añades el html donde se encuentra tambien puede ser util. Gracias.

Comment: gracias, J. BARRIO, otra vez!! la pagina es www.infocif.es y uso el navegador Fireforx.. He hecho un codigo y me funciona la secuencia: cargar navegador+introducir valor del CIF  en el input  y dar intro (lo hago con submit) y me funcionó pero ahora me sale este texto que me "para".

Comment: las primeras veces que lo probé no me salía el texto y por eso me funcionó el codigo (eran 4 lineas...) de las copio..

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\\Users\\Usuario\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe')


driver.get('http://www.infocif.es')






cif= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtempresabusquedaprincipal']")

cif.send_keys('ELQUESEA')

cif.submit()

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException



driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'c:\\Users\\Usuario\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\selenium\\webdriver\\geckodriver.exe')


driver.get('http://www.infocif.es')






cif= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtempresabusquedaprincipal']")

cif.send_keys('ELQUESEA')

cif.submit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al acceder a la pagina a mi ya me sale el aceptar la politica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y asi lo he hecho yo:

```
driver.get('infocif.es') 
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='acepta_cookies']//a[text()='Aceptar']").click()
cif=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='txtempresabusquedaprincipal']")
```

Aunque si quieres que no dependa del idioma esta opcion tambien seria valida:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='acepta_cookies']//a[2]").click()
```

Comment: nice and easy!! eres un crack!

Comment: Por favor, marca la pregunta como [correcta y resuelta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), si eres tan amable.

Comment: no sé como se hace,, disculpa

Comment: @JoseMiguel completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento básico del sitio (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla), y lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers) en el centro de ayuda para más información.